# How can I insert a line break after the captionlabel (koma-script options)?

Tags: captions, koma-script

On page 125 in [`scrguien.pdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), the two lower captions have a line break after the label. How can I do the same for my captions? Is that even possible with built-in KOMA options? Looked for a good 15 minutes now and so far, no luck. :/

### Picture of Markus's output, what I would like to have as well

[image]

### My MWE

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% built-in KOMA caption specifications
\setcapmargin{1cm}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
AAA
\caption{Test.}
\end{table}
\begin{center}
BBB
\captionof{table}{Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The options listed in those captions are the options required to produce those captions... just pick the one you want and put either `\setcapindent*{1em}` or `\setcapindent{-1em}` on a line near the other caption settings...

Comment: Noted. `indent` is not a clear pointer towards a line break, thought it was moot point to consider these options further.

Comment: the line breaking is clearly explained with the explanation of those commands on the bottom of the previous page.

Comment: @PaulGessler Oh... :) ah well who reads the manual in full these days anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\setcapindent*`; note the difference when the argument is positive or negative. I used the command in the `center` environment, but of course you should make a global decision in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

%% built-in KOMA caption specifications
\setcaphanging
\setcapmargin{1cm}
\setcapindent*{0pt}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
AAA
\caption{Test.}
\end{table}
\begin{center}
BBB

\captionof{table}{Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. 
Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12.}

\setcapindent*{1em}

\captionof{table}{Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. 
Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12.}

\setcapindent*{-1em}

\captionof{table}{Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12. 
Some more words 12. Some more words 12. Some more words 12.}


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wanted the global option (of course), very good to explicitly mention it.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommand the `caption`-package:
http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf

It delivers a huge amount of possibilities to customize captions.

the behavior you desire would be achieved with:

```
\usepackage[labelsep=newline,            % Caption starts in a new line below the label
            format=hang,                 % Caption hangs under the label
            indentation=-1em]{caption}   % and moved back by 1em
```